# What does the term Reference Implementation mean

Tags: java, jsf

I have been working on JSF, I came across the term RI (Reference Implementation). What is this RI. Also, is this restricted only to JSF framework or do all frameworks have this?

Answer (score 5):

JSF is a *specification* -- a textual description of a software system. In theory, at least, there could be many different *implementations* of that specification; multiple vendors could all implement their own versions of the spec, all of which followed the specification, but some were faster, or more robust, or used less memory, etc. The *reference implementation* is simply the implementation of a specification that is offered as an example of how the specification might be implemented. Having a RI makes it easier for other implementors to understand the intent of a specification. Sometimes the RI is just a toy, and no one uses it; other times, the RI is also the best implementation.

This is not unique to JSF -- virtually all Java specs have an RI, and very often the RI is the implementation most developers use.

Comment: An additional benefit of an RI (if it is created in parallel to the specification) is the feedback it provides to the specification authors. It proofs that the specification can be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

One of the things characterizing the overall development of Java is that new facilities coming out of Sun (who invented Java and later was bought by Oracle) was designed as a specification.

A specification is a document for programmers to read describing the way the code is expected to work, either for those who need to implement the specification in their code or for those needing to understand how an existing implementation is expected to work.

Part of having a specification pass the full JSR process is to provide a reference implementation, which implements the specification.  Often also a test framework is provided so it can be verified that a given implementation conforms to the specification (which can then be reused for other implementations if needed).  The reference implementation is not required to be the best or fastest, just to provide a correct implementation.

This approach (describe the API, not provide a binary platform) is the reason why the Java world has numerous servlet containers, and application servers because Sun took the time to craft the interfaces, and encouraged others to implement them too.

Comment: Indeed, with the open source version of Glassfish being one whopping huge reference implementation of the JEE platform. Its a bit of an outlandish example however since the JEE platform envelops many interfaces, most of which have reference implementations :) JAXB, JAXP, JAX-WS, JAX-RS, JSF, CDI, ...