# What is Java EE reference implementation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

> Unlike the Java EE standard, MicroProfile does not have a reference
>   implementation but only TCKs (test compatibility kits) to pass.

(MicroProfile Technical White Paper, Lars Röwekamp)

I know GlassFish has served as a reference implementation of Java EE. I want to know what exactly is a reference implementation?

Comment: And [What does the term Reference Implementation mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041158/what-does-the-term-reference-implementation-mean).

Comment: Also see [Reference implementation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_implementation).